# Problema con serverTimestamp() de Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

En un servicio tengo esta función:

```html
agregarAutor(Autor: Shirt)
   {
     Autor.idtime= firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
     return this.shirtCollection.add(Autor);

   }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Firebase se inserta el campo "idtime" con un valor como: "16 de febrero de 2021, 19:37:23 UTC+1", pero me gustaría que se guardase con una resolución de tiempo mayor, como milisegundos o algo más, porque tengo miedo de que se guarden dos documentos con el mismo valor de tiempo. Hay alguna forma de convertir esa fecha en un número entero como el total de segundos (no sé si a eso se le llama "Tiempo Unix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los timestamp de firebase tienen precision de nanosegundos. Como puedes ver en la [referencia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp), `Timestamp` es una clase sencilla con apenas 2 propiedades: `seconds` y `nanoseconds`. En otras palabras, ya es un número en tiempo unix. La consola lo muestra como string simplemente para que puedas entenderlo.

> tengo miedo de que se guarden dos documentos con el mismo valor de tiempo

No hay nada de que preocuparse, no es posible que dos documentos tengan el mismo timestamp. Así que todo lo que tienes que hacer es darle gracias al Firebase Team.

Comment: Si, pero en Firebase no veo que guarde los nanosegundos. Y otra cosa: hay algún tipo de dato "timestamp" en Angular?

Comment: No muestra los nanosegundos porque no te serviría de mucho verlos. La clase `Timestamp`, mas precisamente `firebase.firestore.Timestamp` viene en el SDK official para js. Así que siempre la tendrás disponible independientemente del framework que uses. Todas las librerías específicas (AngularFire, ReactFire, etc) tienen ese SDK como dependencia. Puedes crear un timestamp local escribiendo `Timestamp.now()` pero es más confiable dejar que lo cree el servidor como haces en tu codigo